# Which moon is best? (for gravity assists)

Tags: orbital-mechanics, gravity-assist, moons

Inspired by [my answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55837/40257) to [Is a ballistic Jovian capture using the Galilean moons possible from interplanetary entry?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55668/40257) in which I discovered that Callisto offers a stronger gravity assist than Ganymede despite being less massive.

This is because Callisto is further from Jupiter than Ganymede and thus, in a trajectory gravitationally dominated by Jupiter, an object will encounter Callisto with significantly less relative velocity ($V_{\infty}$). The strength of gravity assist can be realized as the amount it deflects a trajectory:

$$\delta = 2 \cdot sin^{-1} \biggr ( \frac{1}{1 + \frac{r_p \cdot V_{\infty}^2}{\mu}} \biggr)$$

The strength can also be quantified as a $\Delta V$:

$$\Delta V = V_{\infty} \cdot \sqrt{2-2 \cdot \cos{\delta}}$$

**Question:** Which moon in the solar system can provide the strongest gravity assist considering an object on an interplanetary arrival trajectory (initially hyperbolic at the host planet) deflection and $\Delta V$ wise?

Comment: That's a very complex question, because *obviously* you would not only be affected by the moon's gravity, but also the planet the moon orbits. In the case of Jupiter, that is some *massive* (pun intended) influence

Comment: @CuteKItty_pleaseStopBArking the complexity lowers significantly in the case where the parent planet /body accounts for the high high majority of system mass (like with Jupiter). Consider a gravity assist around Jupiter itself; the Sun's gravity doesn't play a big role outside of determining $V_{\infty}$ for the hyperbolic flyby of Jupiter

Comment: Gee, this is *interesting!*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a selection from [Wikipedia's List of natural satellites](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_natural_satellites) (moons with listed masses) I, with some simplifying assumptions, calculated both the deflection, $\delta$, and $\Delta V$ for each moon.

In all cases the moons were assumed to be in a circular orbit around the parent planet. To find the $V_{\infty}$ for the encounter, I calculated the orbital speed, $V$, about the parent planet at the moon's orbital radius for a $V_{\infty}=0$, technically parabolic but more or less hyperbolic (and fair between planets), arrival. I then subtracted and added the moon's orbital speed (circular orbit speed at moon's semi-major axis) to get the $V_{\infty}$.

Differing encounter geometry between the trajectory and the moon means that $V_{\infty}$ is bounded by $V-V_{moon}$ as a minimum (prograde) and $V+V_{moon}$ as a maximum (retrograde).

The equations given in the question can then be used where the flyby close approach, $r_p$, is the moon's radius (+500 km for Titan).

Here is the retrograde case (logarithmic scale):

[image: retrograde logarithmic plot]

And here is the prograde case (logarithmic scale):

[image: prograde logarithmic plot]

Zooming in on the top right (logarithmic scale):

[image: Best moons]

**Answer:**

In $\Delta V$ terms; a prograde Titan gravity assist is strongest at $1.63$ $km/s$. In deflection terms; a prograde gravity assist by the Moon is strongest at $140°$.

---

#### P.S.

The Moon exhibits a unique variation on the plot from retrograde to prograde, different from any other moon (at least of those shown in the zoomed in view). All of the other moons have a positive 'slope', if you will, while the Moon has a negative 'slope' from retrograde to prograde. I believe this is because, as [Wikipedia states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moon):

> [The Moon] is the largest natural satellite in the Solar System relative to the size of its planet

But I don't understand how this mechanism works. I did make two cool Desmos plots though showing the variation from prograde to retrograde:

[image: Titan variation]

[image: The Moon variation]

Comment: Some moons smaller than Pluto's moon Charon are included. Pluto isn't a "planet", but can you/your reference tell wherea its large moon would fall on these plots?